# Callback in a double loop

Tags: loops, callback

I have seen examples of callbacks inside a loop where the loop needs to wait for the callback and I don't get how to apply those answers to my script.

I actually have a double loop like that:

```
var marker = [{43.000,-79.321},...];
var result = [];

function test(){
    for(var i=0; i<marker.length;i++){
        result[i] =[];
        for(var j=0; j<marker.length;j++){
            drivingDistance(marker[i],marker[j],i,j,function(cb){
                result[cb.i][cb.j] = cb.distance;
            });
        }
    }
}

function drivingDistance(Point1,Point2,i,j,cb){
    cb({distance:'something',i:i,j:j});
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a native recursion alternative, here's a way to do it

```
var marker = [[43.000,-79.321],[44.000,-79],[45.000,-78],[46.000,-77]];
var result = [];
var i=0, j=0;

function test(){
    if(j >= marker.length){ j=0; i++; } // j is done one lap, reset to 0, i++ for next lap
    if(i >= marker.length){ return false; } // if there are no more laps, stop recursion
    if(j == 0){ result[i] = []; } // new lap, set result[i] as empty

    drivingDistance(marker[i],marker[j],i,j,function(cb){
        result[cb.i][cb.j] = cb.distance;
        j++; // increment j before next recursion
        test();
    });
}

function drivingDistance(Point1,Point2,i,j,cb){
    cb({distance:'something',i:i,j:j});
}

test();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use square brackets `[` and `]` to hold your points instead of `curly` ones

```
var marker = [[43.000,-79.321]]; // instead of [{43.000,-79.321}]
              ^              ^
```

Then, you simply need to use deferred/promise concept to synchronize all your internal callbacks as follows

```
var marker = [[43.000,-79.321]];
var result = [];

function test(){
    var deferreds = [];

    for(var i=0; i<marker.length;i++){
        result[i] =[];
        for(var j=0; j<marker.length;j++){

            // add all your deferred instances returned by drivingDistance
            deferreds.push( drivingDistance(marker[i],marker[j],i,j) );
        }
    }

  $.when.apply(null, deferreds).then(function() {
    var cbs = arguments,
        cb
    ;

    for(var j = 0 ; j < cbs.length ; j++) {
      cb = cbs[j];
      result[cb.i][cb.j] = cb.distance;
    }

  }).done(function() {

      // You can safely print out the result array
      console.log(result);
  });

}

function drivingDistance(Point1,Point2,i,j,cb){

    var d = $.Deferred();

    d.resolve({distance:'something',i:i,j:j});

    return d;
}  

test();
```

See [jQuery.When](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) for more information

Comment: You should point out in your answer the code errors too :) - the ones you [edited the question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8519581) to resolve